# R: Interpretation of p-value in urca Dickey-Fuller test?

Tags: r, time-series, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

I'm checking my variables for stationarity and can't figure out how to interpret the p-value listed in the output of the Dickey-Fuller test from the `urca` package. It seems to be inconsistent with the t-stat and critical values.

Comparing results from `urca` with those from the `tseries` package seems to suggest that the p-value in `urca` means something different.

I've read a number of similar posts but haven't found an answer to this particular question.

Below is the code I'm running (the first bit runs the `urca` DF test, the second runs the `tseries` DF test). I've used zero lags in both cases to make sure the models are consistent.

```
# Dickey-Fuller
df <- ur.df(varslvl_pre$px, type = 'trend', lags = 0)
summary(df)

adf.test(varslvl_pre$px, k = 0)
```

Here is the output from the `urca` test:

```r
> summary(df)

############################################### 
# Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root Test # 
############################################### 

Test regression trend 


Call:
lm(formula = z.diff ~ z.lag.1 + 1 + tt)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.3900 -0.4439 -0.1713  0.4758  3.6120 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.493466   0.260020   1.898 0.061000 .  
z.lag.1     -0.275098   0.079786  -3.448 0.000869 ***
tt           0.022413   0.008619   2.600 0.010922 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.146 on 88 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1223,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1023 
F-statistic: 6.129 on 2 and 88 DF,  p-value: 0.003222


Value of test-statistic is: -3.4479 4.1221 6.1288 

Critical values for test statistics: 
      1pct  5pct 10pct
tau3 -4.04 -3.45 -3.15
phi2  6.50  4.88  4.16
phi3  8.73  6.49  5.47
```

The t-stat for the coefficient on the variable `z.lag.1` is -3.448, and the corresponding p-value is 0.000869. However, further down in the output, the critical values for `tau3` suggest that the p-value should be slightly above 5%.

Now, here is the output from the `tseries` test:

```r
    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  varslvl_pre$px
Dickey-Fuller = -3.4479, Lag order = 0, p-value = 0.05182
alternative hypothesis: stationary
```

The t-stat is the same as before (-3.4479), but the p-value is 0.0518 -- which seems to be consistent with the critical values from `urca` but is vastly different from `urca`'s p-value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The p-value given by `lm()`, called by `ur.df()`, is not the correct p-value
for the ADF test. It's the usual p-value computed under stationarity assumptions, which does not hold under the unit-root null.

The p-values should be computed using the correct asymptotic distribution and critical values (which is part of the output).